# Which instruction to follow while enabling platform views?

Tags: flutter

> While installing google_maps_flutter plug-in, it's required to enable embedded view on iOS side. According to the instructions on [pub.dev page of google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter#-readme-tab-), one needs to add the key `io.flutter.embedded_views_preview` into Info.plist file with the value `YES`. As a developer with Android Development background, I find this a bit confusing. The statement does not specify the type of value which in this case is ´YES´. On the other hand, I've seen people using value `<true/>`. This usage can be found in the **[Adding Google Maps to a Flutter App](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/google-maps-in-flutter/#0)** codelab as well. I've successfully added google_maps_flutter plugin to my app by using `<true/>`. Which way to do this is the right one? Am I missing something related to Info.plist file and the way it works?

Answer (score 0):

The confusion is caused by the way you're viewing the .plist file. If you're opening the `Info.plist` as `Property List` (Right Click on Info.plist -> Open As -> Property List) then the value you have to set is `YES/NO` if the value type of your property is set to ```Boolean````.

If you open the `Info.plist` as source code (Right Click on Info.plist -> Open As -> Source Code) which is just a simple XML file, the correct value is .

So technically both options have the same result depending on how you view the property list.